# How to merge hashes inside array?

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

How do I merge the hashes in these arrays:

```
description = [
  { description: "Lightweight, interpreted, object-oriented language ..." },
  { description: "Powerful collaboration, review, and code management ..." }
]

title = [
  { title: "JavaScript" },
  { title: "GitHub" }
]
```

so I get:

```rb
[
  {
    description: "Lightweight, interpreted, object-oriented language ...",
    title: "JavaScript"
  },
  {
    description: "Powerful collaboration, review, and code management ...",
    title: "GitHub"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If 1) thare are only 2 lists to merge, 2) you're sure the lists are of the same length and 3) nth item of list `l1` must be merged with nth item of `l2` (e.g. items are properly ordered in both lists) this can be done as simple as

```
l1.zip(l2).map { |a,b| a.merge(b) }
```

Comment: The term "array" would be more appropriate. Regarding 1) – `zip` and `merge` can both handle multiple arguments, e.g. `l1.zip(l2, l3).map { |a, b, c| a.merge(b, c) }`

Comment: exactly, every list has same length but i have more than two lists. The answer from @Rajagopalan is just fine two lists are matching with title and description. Now I am trying for multiple lists. If you have any suggestion plz comment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code

```
firstArray=[{:description=>"\nLightweight, interpreted, object-oriented language with first-class functions\n"}, {:description=>"\nPowerful collaboration, review, and code management for open source and private development projects\n"}]

secondArray=[{:title=>"JavaScript"}, {:title=>"GitHub"}]

result=firstArray.map do |v|
  v1=secondArray.shift
  v.merge(v1)
end

p result
```

Result

```
[{:description=>"\nLightweight, interpreted, object-oriented language with first-class functions\n", :title=>"JavaScript"}, {:description=>"\nPowerful collaboration, review, and code management for open source and private development projects\n", :title=>"GitHub"}]
```

Comment: `shift` will modify the 2nd array.

Answer (score 0):

```
description = [
  { description: "Lightweight, interpreted" },
  { description: "Powerful collaboration" }
]

title = [
  { title: "JavaScript" },
  { title: "GitHub" }
]
```

```
description.each_index.map { |i| description[i].merge(title[i]) }
  #=> [{:description=>"Lightweight, interpreted",
  #     :title=>"JavaScript"},
  #    {:description=>"Powerful collaboration",
  #     :title=>"GitHub"}]
```

When using `zip` the temporary array `description.zip(title)` is constructed. By contrast, the method above creates no intermediate array.